# How to add objects in array

Tags: reactjs

A am trying to create one array of objects in reactjs.

I have data defined in my state:

```
this.state ={
   data:[]
}
```

I have two dropdowns, on changing the dropdown value some value populated from one csv file.

Like from *dropdown1*, I got `[1,2,3,4,5]` and from *dropdown2* I got `[10,20,30,40,50]` and now I want to add these value in below format in data (in state) using `setState`:

```
data:[
   {"x":1,"y":10},{"x":2,"y":20},{"x":3,"y":30},{"x":4,"y":40},{"x":5,"y":50}
]
```

I have two `handleChange` functions for each dropdown.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i don't know how you fetch data for `Dropdown1` and `Dropdown2`, but from the following example let's say you already have it inside `state`:

```
this.state = {
  data: [],
  firstDropdown: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  secondDropdown: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
}
```

Note: Both *dropdowns* **are same length**!

To populate `Data Array` use React `ComponentDidMount` [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle):

```
ComponentDidMount() {
  const { firstDropdown, secondDropdown } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    data: firstDropdown.map((x, i) => ({ x, y: secondDropdown[i] }))
  })
}
```

`ComponentDidMount` is the **best place** to put calls to **fetch data**.

Full example:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        firstDropdown: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        secondDropdown: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const { firstDropdown, secondDropdown } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      data: firstDropdown.map((x, i) => ({ x, y: secondDropdown[i] })),
    })
  }
  
  handleChangeFirst = e => {
    console.log("First", e.target.value)
  }
  
  handleChangeSecond = e => {
    console.log("Second", e.target.value)
  }
  
  render() {
    
  return (
     <div>
       <p>First</p>
       <select onChange={this.handleChangeFirst}>
         {this.state.firstDropdown.map(x => <option key={x} value={x}>{x}</option>)}
       </select>
       <p>Second</p>
       <select onChange={this.handleChangeSecond}>
         {this.state.secondDropdown.map(x => <option key={x} value={x}>{x}</option>)}
       </select>
       <h4>Data state</h4>
       <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}
       </pre>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.9/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.9/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Helpful link: [Official React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
dropDownChange1(e) => {
  this.setState({
     x: e.target.value
  });
}
dropDownChange2(e) => {
  this.setState({
     y: e.target.value
  });
}
```

Let's say you have a `Add button` which has an `onClick function` to add these values to the `data Array`

```
addMyValues() => {
  let obj = {
   "x": this.state.x, "y": this.state.y
  }
  let myArray = this.state.data;
  myArray.push(obj);
  this.setState({data : myArray});
}
```

Hope this helps. And just a humble request, next time when you ask a question please try to provide the entire code including the `html` markup. It makes it easy to help understand the problem.

Do let me know if the above code helps.

Comment: State is `immutable`. Your `Array.push` will mutate the state.

Comment: Mutation is still there. `Objects are reference types`. Use `Array.concat` instead `Array.push`.